# How to replace the deprecated gtk3 GtkImageMenuItem

Tags: c, gtk3, deprecation-warning

The [official GTK3 documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkImageMenuItem.html#gtk-image-menu-item-new) for replacement is a bad joke:

> Use gtk_menu_item_new() instead.

After some research it almost feels like the GTK team wants to punish GTK package users. Of course, `gtk_menu_item` has no native support for images. I found [this piece of code](https://git.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-dict/tree/lib/gui.c#n372) which seems to be the recommend approach but it produces menu items with ugly left padding:

[image: ugly left padding]

First item on the picture uses the recommended replacement. All other items use the deprecated `GtkImageMenuItem`. Here the related code creating the first item:

```c
mi = gtk_menu_item_new();
box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 6);
icon = gtk_image_new_from_icon_name ("document-open", GTK_ICON_SIZE_MENU);
label = gtk_label_new (_("Open"));
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), icon);
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), label);
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (mi), box);
gtk_widget_show_all(mi);
gtk_widget_set_sensitive(mi, TRUE);
gtk_menu_shell_append (GTK_MENU_SHELL (menu), mi);
```

I have no idea how to get rid of that ugly left-padding. If the padding would vanish, I could go for this approach.

Another option to replace `GtkImageMenuItem` seems to be to write a own subclass of [`GtkMenuItem`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuItem.html). Which would be a lot of work. Maybe there are some implementations around?

Yet another option seems to be the usage of [`GMenu`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GMenu.html) instead of `GtkMenu`. `GMenu` provides [`g_menu_item_set_icon`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GMenu.html#g-menu-item-set-icon). However, replacing the whole menu is a drastic step (and I did not check so far how it would look like).

By the way: why exactly are there two different menu approaches in Glib/GTK which are not compatible with each other?

Any hints on which would be the best way to go for me ?

Comment: For the record: I've tried with
`GtkCssProvider *mi_css_provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
  gtk_style_context_add_provider (gtk_widget_get_style_context (mi), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (mi_css_provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (mi_css_provider, ".menuitem { padding-left: 0px; } ",  -1, NULL);`
This moves the icon a bit to the left, but unfortunately only a few pixels. And negative padding is not possible.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57411101/big-gaps-in-menu-using-gmenu/57422036#57422036

Answer (score 2):

GTK just doesn't intend to support image menu items going forward. (They're considered bad practice in modern UI by some.) However, you don't *have* to replace it just because it's deprecated; it will continue to work in GTK 3.x. If you wanted to continue to use it in GTK 4 and beyond you could create your own subclass but the path of least resistance is probably to just go with the flow and avoid mixing images in the menus.

As for the screenshot above I would expect that the left padding might disappear if you removed the other image menu items and replaced them with your replacement code. In that case you could put extra left padding on the menu items where you didn't add images, using CSS.

Comment: Just took a try to remove all other menu items. It did not help, the padding on the left is still there.  It looks like the space is "reserved" for something. Since I want to go for gtk4 in the long run, and I dont want to follow arbitrary gtk considerations, it looks like I will go for my own image-menu-item widget.

Comment: I guess the space is probably reserved for the checkboxes of checkbox menu items, in that case. Sorry the suggestion didn't help.

Comment: Space reservation for checkboxes can be disabled by `gtk_menu_set_reserve_toggle_size(menu, false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed for me by adding a negative margin left to the box

Here is an example but in Rust:

```rs
let box_container = gtk::Box::new(Orientation::Horizontal, 6);
let style_context = box_container.style_context();
let css_provider = gtk::CssProvider::new();
let theme = r#"
   box {
     margin-left: -22px;
   }
"#;
box_container.pack_start(&image, false, false, 0);
box_container.pack_start(&label, true, true, 0);
box_container.show_all();
let _ = css_provider.load_from_data(theme.as_bytes());
```

[image]