# Big gaps in Menu using GMenu

Tags: c, linux, gtk

When creating a menu using GMenu (Gnome/Gtk) there is a huge gap left to the labels of the menu items(-> Picture). Any thoughts how to fix this?

```c
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib-object.h>
#include <glib/gi18n.h>

//....
//....


if(title && (action || submenu))
{
   GMenuItem *item;

   if(submenu)
   {
      item = g_menu_item_new_submenu (title, G_MENU_MODEL(submenu));
   }
   else
   {
      item = g_menu_item_new(title, action);
      if (icon != NULL)
      {
         g_menu_item_set_attribute (item, "icon", "s", icon);
      }
   }

//.....
//....
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Bs8.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that's the way it's [intended to be](https://developer.gnome.org/GMenu/#Icons).
You can stick to the deprecated `GtkImageMenuItem` which is not problem until you port your app to GTK 4. If you really want to avoid deprecated components, it's possible to wrap an image + label in a `GtkBox` as suggested by the documentation, although it's not so straightforward, there are some needed quirks to get a decent solution:

1. You need to use `gtk_menu_set_reserve_toggle_size` on the menu and set that to `FALSE`.
2. Then you need to create the label and image for each menu item, however for items without icons it's necessary to create an image that will act as a filler, i.e. `gtk_image_new_from_icon_name ("", GTK_ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)`

You can find a fully working sample [here](https://gist.github.com/andreldm/62ecee0d87cde8ec5f3d0e36e404511c).

**Note:** there is no guarantee this will properly work on GTK 4.